# Awk splitting one file into n files each one with its header

Tags: awk, split

I am having a hardtime trying to learn how to have 2 output files based on the header and if its possible named with info from the header...

Example original file:

```
AAABBB12042018

 Jon238444kdhsljdjd7

 Math37378338kdjdkske

AAABBB14042018

 Ash81272722mddnd

 Jay81727272msnsms
```

1st file named based on header: `file-12042018`

```
Jon238444kdhsljdjd

Math37378338kdjdkske
```

2nd file named based on header: `file-14042018`

```
Ash81272722mddnd

Jay81727272msnsms
```

I dont mind keeping the header or not, my issue is how to handle multiple output names based on a string within the header

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Comment: is the "AAABBB" part constant? How do we know that it's the header? Is it the lack of leading spaces?

Comment: Gleen its a costant it means its the header exactly that string

Answer (score 0):

this should do...

```
$ awk '/^AAABBB/{sub(/^AAABBB/,"file-"); fn=$0; next} {print > fn}' file
```

if the line starts with this token, replace it with file prefix and print lines to that file.